# Getting the IP Address from a device

Tags: cisco, mac-address

I got some kind of "router" from another department and they want to know the IP address.

I connected it for "testing" purpose on the switch at our place. I know the switch and port its connected to also in which VLAN it is.

But I dont see it on the MAC address-table neither in the ARP table.
It is on a L3 switch and we have 2 core switches. This is all I know and I'm stuck.

Comment: sry for the minimal Info. I'm pretty new into "business Networking" and have no Instructuer or anything as my mentor left the company early. How do i get you what you need?

Comment: in cisco device 'sh run' command. if you want to see directly connected devices details including ip address using '  cdp neib detail'

Comment: i cant run 'cdp neib detail' for any reason 

and the sh run is pretty long without any viable information on my side

Comment: What brand of router?  There must be a label on it.

Comment: @RonTrunk it is labeld as  "Conel UR5i v2"

Comment: It is this device? http://www.comm2m.fr/images/produits/docs/CONEL/comM2M_CONEL_UR5iv2.pdf

Comment: @JFL yep exactly this device I dont even know what this is used for

Comment: It is a Cellular modem used for [MODBUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus) applications (communication with industrial machines).

Comment: @JFL well i'm just the "new" sysadmin who should find that out because they cant but I should be the savior and have no clue from this thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can access the "router" via console port you should be able to get its IP configuration by `show running` or `show ip`.

If the device is using DHCP for its IP configuration you can check your DHCP server's lease table for the device MAC (the MAC should be printed on the case).

If the device uses a locally configured IP address that doesn't even match the actual IP subnet there are some other ways to find out:

- the device might identify itself via LLDP or CDP - check on the uplink switch by `show cdp neighbors`, `show lldp neighbors`, `show lldp info remote` or similar
- connect the device to a packet capturing machine - some packets likely reveal its IP address (like ARP requests for its default gateway or DNS server)
- like the previous step, but still connected to the switch, set up port mirroring on the device's uplink port

[edit]

I found the (German) *Conel UR5i v2* manual through Google - as it appears, that router has a default address of `192.168.1.1`. Also by default, **its DHCP server is active** so you shouldn't connect it to a production network without appropriate configuration. If you just connect your computer to the Ethernet port you should be able to access its web GUI on https://192.168.1.1

Comment: Thank you for the Informations but as it seems I can't access it. I tried it even with a static IP. I will ask the other department if it is configured in any way and if I can factory reset it. Otherwise it seems i can't get any infos about it.